# How to fail maven goal sonar:sonar based on quality gates

Tags: maven, sonarqube

How to fail maven goal sonar:sonar based on quality gates rules?
I run it for local builds, for CI I already wrote a script according to http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Breaking+the+CI+Build
So, if quality gates validation fails then goal also should fails

Comment: normally quality gates are applied to sonar scans and make a CI job (i.e. Jenkins job) fail, but not for local builds, do you already have such CI flow in place or do you only seek it for local builds?

Comment: I only seek it for local builds, I have such flow for CI I wrote a script according to http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Breaking+the+CI+Build

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added the script as post step command, so after build succeeded the script check quality gates and breaks the job if they are not ok.

Comment: what If you need some build steps to be skipped depending on the quality gate result? e.g. generation of maven artifacts, release creation etc. would you put all this in post release steps?

Answer (score 6):

If Sonar Qube Version is bigger than 8.1, following command can be used:

```
mvn verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true
```

Comment: thank you! it solved it for me

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [SonarQube Build Breaker plugin](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-build-breaker).

It's a controversy feature as explained in the blog post [Why You Shouldn't Use Build Breaker](https://blog.sonarsource.com/why-you-shouldnt-use-build-breaker/).

It is also possible to integrate with Jenkins use web hook (see the blog post [Breaking the SonarQube Analysis with Jenkins Pipelines](https://blog.sonarsource.com/breaking-the-sonarqube-analysis-with-jenkins-pipelines/)).

Comment: The links are dead. An update would be most appreciated.

Comment: I still can access them? What do you mean by dead?

Comment: Interesting. With Firefox 59.0.2 on Ubuntu 17.10 I get a 404 while with Chrome they're indeed accessible. Probably a script blocking issue anyway. My bad.

Comment: There is no point in worring about creating a synchronous process from an async one. This is literally nonesense if you have a clear goal and do it right. So do not fear to use a web-crawling solution or a plugin to achieve your goal.